# How to manually change color and symbols for a scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatterplot where based on the x and y range the point on the plot is assigned a color and a symbol. The symbols can be the same if the colors of the points are different. I would also like for the legend to display the question name of each of the points as well as the symbol and correct color in descending order of the y and x value summed.

So far I have the colors mapped but have not figured out the symbols and the legend. This is my function so far (The function is necessary because this needs to be replicated for dfs with different row counts):

```
surveyfunct <- function(SurveyAll) {
  SurveyAll <- SurveyAll %>%
    mutate(
      Value = as.numeric(if_else(grepl("^[0-9]+$", Answer), Answer, NA_character_)),
      Frequency = if_else(is.na(Value), Answer, NA_character_)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(Question = gsub("\\s*\\d+$", "", Question)) %>% 
    mutate(Frequency = case_when(
      Frequency == "Almost Never" ~ 1,
      Frequency== "Seldom" ~ 2,
      Frequency == "Sometimes" ~ 3,
      Frequency == "Often" ~ 4,
      Frequency == "Almost Always" ~ 5,
      Frequency == "None" ~ 1,
      Frequency == "Few" ~ 2,
      Frequency == "Some" ~ 3,
      Frequency == "Many" ~ 4,
      Frequency == "Almost All" ~ 5,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_ # For character answers that don't match any case
    ))
  
  SurveyAll <- SurveyAll %>%
    group_by(Question) %>%
    summarise(
      Average_Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
      Average_Frequency = mean(Frequency, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    mutate(Color_Code = case_when(
      Average_Value >= 1 & Average_Value <= 3 & Average_Frequency >= 1 & Average_Frequency <= 3 ~ "green",
      Average_Value > 3 & Average_Value <= 5 & Average_Frequency >= 1 & Average_Frequency <= 3 ~ "red",
      Average_Value > 3 & Average_Value <= 5 & Average_Frequency > 3 & Average_Frequency <= 5 ~ "yellow",
      TRUE ~ "black" # Default color
    )) %>%
    select(Question, Average_Value, Average_Frequency, Color_Code)
  
  ggplot(SurveyAll, aes(x = Average_Value, y = Average_Frequency, color = Color_Code)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = 1:5) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = 1:5) +
    labs(title = "Scatter Plot of Average Value vs. Average Frequency",
         x = "Average Value",
         y = "Average Frequency") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green", "black")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right")
}
```

Comment: I am not complety sure that this will fit your needs since I can't reproduce your example. But try to put `shape` in the `aes()` of your `ggplot()`. Ex.

`df = data.frame(x =1:3, y= c(10, 10, 11), z=c("A","B","B"))

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, shape= z))+

  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2))`